# php list split array as options

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

Ok so tbh the title isn't very good I just don't know how to explain what i'm trying to do in 1 short sentence so I will do my best here....

I have an array

```
$options = array('156656', 'bar', '235456','soft', '353636','eve', '4356563', 'evil');
```

I want number and name to be partnered/linked so have done this by splitting with list() ...

```
list($number, $name) = $options; 

echo $name . ' : ' . $number . '<br />';
```

which shows as

```
 156656 : bar
```

but what I need is for all to be listed like so ...

```
156656 : bar
235456 : soft
353636 : eve
4356563 : evil
```

I'm guessing this is done with a foreach but what ever I try fails

As always all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get sub arrays like below:

```
$options = array('1', 'bar', '2','soft', '3','eve', '4', 'evil');
foreach (array_chunk($options, 2) as $sub) {
     list($number, $name) = $sub; 
     echo $number . ' : ' . $name . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about enumerating two at a time:

```
for ($i = 0; 2 * $i < count($arr); ++$i)
{
  print("First: " . $arr[2 * $i] . ", Second: " $arr[2 * $i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: ok I see what you mean but the number in my list isn't actually necessarily in order, maybe I will edit my question

Comment: It doesn't matter if numbers in your list are in order or not, the above loop will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using associative arrays, for this application, as well:

`$options = array('156656'=>'bar', '235456'=>'soft', '353636'=>'eve', '4356563'=>'evil');`

Then, you can use foreach on it as so:

```
foreach($options as $key=>$value){
   print("$key: $value\n");
}
```